# trying to learn regex however my code doesn't display the correct output

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a small program that can locate http and https links in a piece of text. Just beginning to learn about regular expressions but i cant understand what i am doing wrong with my code. Rather than displaying the link it displays "no website found". Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
 import re
 correctURL = re.compile(r'(HTTPS://|HTTP://) \S+', re.I)
 myURL = "HTTPS://w"
 match = correctURL.search(myURL)
 if match:
     print("The website found was:" + match.group(0))
 else:
     print("No website was found")
```

Comment: Remove the space from the RE, then it will match.

Comment: still doesnt seem to work

Comment: What do you expect as output?

Comment: to print the website, in this case just "https://w" however it prints no website found.

Answer (score 0):

Only two minor modifications are necessary:

(i) Omitting the space from the pattern, and grouping the "rest" of the URL so that it can be referenced later

(ii) When a match is found, we print the 2nd group. (`group(0)` is the whole match, `group(1)` is the 1st etc.)

```
correctURL = re.compile(r'(HTTPS://|HTTP://)(\S+)', re.I)
myURL = "HTTPS://w"
match = correctURL.search(myURL)
if match:
    print("The website found was:" + match.group(2))
else:
    print("No website was found")
```

I wonder if this is already what you need, or you may want to extract the domain name as well, as suggested by the wording "website".

Comment: Okay, thanks very much that seemed to work. I have one more question though, what if i wanted to change the .search(myURL) to .findall(myURL). I tried this but it gave me the error AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: Again, the question is what would you like to have as output. And from what input.

Comment: Sorry it doesn't matter, i got it working in the end, but thanks for the advice it really helped.